# out of memory issue in installing packages on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, gcc, ubuntu, memory-management, lxml

I am using a Ubuntu cloud server with limited 512MB RAM and 20 GB HDD. Its 450MB+ RAM is already used by processes.

I need to install a new package called `lxml` which gets complied using `Cpython` while installation and its a very heavy process so it always exits with error `gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)` which is due to no RAM available for it to run.

Upgrading the machine is a choice but it has its own issues and few of my services/websites live from this server itself.

But on my local machine `lxml` is already installed properly. And since my need is `lxml` only, so is it possible that pick all useful files from local machine's directory and copy then into remote machine?

Will it work that way? If yes, how to pick-up all files for a package?

Regards

Comment: how about adding a swap partition/file, should give you enough RAM to install lxml.

Comment: i'm newbie to ubuntu, at-least in case of memory management. can you elaborate further?

Comment: First you need to create a swap file somewhere on the filesystem with the correct size and continuous, like 'sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1024k'. The call 'sudo mkswap /swapfile'  and 'sudo swapon /swapfile'. For a better readable answer, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @TeTeT  It worked well. But how do i delete it without rebooting my server. How will it effect the data already stored on it?

Comment: Make sure that you don't use the swap any longer (free comes in handy)  and then swapoff the file. But take care that it is no longer in use - otherwise your system might get problems. Usually it's best to reboot, though.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Extend your RAM by adding a swap file:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

> a swap file is a file stored on the computer hard drive that is used
>   as a temporary location to store information that is not currently
>   being used by the computer RAM. By using a swap file a computer has
>   the ability to use more memory than what is physically installed in
>   the computer
>   http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/swapfile.htm

In Short:

1. Login as root: `su -` or execute the commands with `sudo` in front
2. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288`
3. `mkswap /swapfile1`
4. `chown root:root /swapfile1`
5. `chmod 0600 /swapfile1`
6. `swapon /swapfile1`

Now the swap file will be activated temporarily, but will be gone after reboot.
You should have enough RAM for your installing process

To Remove the File:

1. `swapoff -v /swapfile1`
2. `rm /swapfile1`

Comment: Wow, it worked well. But how do i delete it without rebooting my server. How will it effect the data already stored on it?

Comment: Edited my Answer, after your installation your system probably won't need the extra space on the swap file, so it should be empty or it will be moved back to your RAM the moment you remove it.

Comment: This answer was a real life saver - not sure why this was the answer yet only had a score of 0.

Comment: Just in case someone is using Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Worked well for me on Fedora 21 Digital Ocean when I was dealing with a memory problem trying to pip install lxml

Comment: Fixes Google CE micro instance issue. Thanks!

Comment: I <3 you. Thanks a lot.