# How to resolve eta 0:00:01Killed?

Tags: pip, pytorch, download, torch

I was downloading torch and after 99% completion of the download, I am getting this error. 
I am using Ubuntu, on an 8gb ram system.

**the memory allocation**

```
ankita@ankita-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.0G        1.6G        495M        4.1G        5.0G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

[image: the error code]

[image: harddisk distribution]

Comment: as you've probably guessed -- you're running out of memory -- maybe try closing chrome?

Comment: but that happened 4 times in a row. But let me try for that too :/

Comment: it didn't helped, the same error again popped out with no background processes running along with.

Comment: Try downloading with other tool, e.g. `wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/ca/306bb933a68b888ab1c20ede0342506b85857635f04fb55a56e53065579b/torch-1.4.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`, then install from disk via `pip install torch --find-links .`

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced this problem due to lack of RAM. You may try increasing the swap space. Try methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57058641/6210807).

The best solution is to install pytorch using `conda`, rather than `pip`. You won't encounter memory error then.

Comment: while installing the same package via conda it says "PackagesNotFoundError"

Comment: Use `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch` for gpu and `conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch` for cpu, check command from [pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).