# pip install torch killed at 99% -- Excessive memory usage

Tags: pip, pytorch

This is while I was installing torch on my laptop. It was getting killed continuously so I thought I will check the memory usage. It hanged my laptop, I had to take a picture with my phone.

If you can't see the image below, it shows pip using 5.8 GiB memory out of 7.8 GiB available. That was a sudden spike at 99%.

[System Monitor pip memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE7I5.jpg)

Comment: try restart and redoing same ?

Comment: Remove all your conda environments and clear your `/root` directory where you install packages.

Comment: Don't use `pip`, use `conda` instead, it'll get installed easily. OR you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058641/pip-install-killed-out-of-memory-how-to-get-around-it

Answer (score 22):

If you are running low on memory you could try with `pip install package --no-cache-dir`