# Can not install tensorflow on ubuntu server 18.04 aws

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

when I pip install tensorflow it was killed

root@cryptofeed:~# pip3 install tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow
Downloading tensorflow-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010x8664.whl (394.8 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 394.7 MB 24.4 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed

root@cryptofeed:~#

I have tried with all version of Tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced this problem due to lack of RAM. You may try increasing the swap space. Try methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058641/pip-install-killed-out-of-memory-how-to-get-around-it#).

Answer (score 0):

"Killed" usually means that a process was killed because it was using more memory than your system would provide.

Check if you have enabled swap.

What is your output of `dmesg`?

How much memory do you have?