# Installation of Pandas fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pandas, installation

As per the Pandas community page (http://pandas.pydata.org/community.html), I am posting here first...

I am trying to install Pandas using pip, inside a virtual environment on a vanilla remote server running Ubuntu 12.04.3 (64bit).  I have already installed the usual suspects (python-dev (2.7), numpy, scipy).  Pandas does not get installed and I am not sure exactly what to change or add to ensure this happens.

I have seen other references (not with the same error) implying that memory may be an issue; the remote server (Digital Ocean droplet) only has 512MB.

The tail of the pip error log is shown below:

```
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------

Command /srv/tp/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/srv/tp/venv/build/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-0bOHrG-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /srv/tp/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /srv/tp/venv/build/pandas

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/tp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/srv/tp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 250, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/srv/tp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1133, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/srv/tp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 577, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/srv/tp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /srv/tp/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/srv/tp/venv/build/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-0bOHrG-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /srv/tp/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /srv/tp/venv/build/pandas
```

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and error on ubuntu and then created a swapfile and it was solved! A tutorial can be found in the link below but in short:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04

After the swap file was created I restarted the server, typed `pip install pandas` and it finally worked.

Answer (score 5):

The most secure way though is just: sudo apt-get install python-pandas

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's out of memory error. At the top of you log, I can see gcc exit with code error 4. When I google it I saw a stackoverflow thread: [Installing lxml with pip in virtualenv Ubuntu 12.10 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149613/installing-lxml-with-pip-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10-error-command-gcc-failed) .