# lxml installation error ubuntu 14.04 (internal compiler error)

Tags: python, installation, pip, lxml, ubuntu-14.04

I am having problems with installing `lxml`. I have tried the solutions of the relative questions in this site and other sites but could not fix the problem. Need some suggestions/solution on this.

I am providing the full log after executing `pip install lxml`,

```
Downloading/unpacking lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.3.5.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KUq9VD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Building lxml version 3.3.5.

Building without Cython.

Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/html

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml

copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/includes

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1

running build_ext

building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KUq9VD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Also, the `pip.log` file looks like this,

```
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KUq9VD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
```

`dmesg | tail` command shows output like this,

```
[1744367.676147] Out of memory: Kill process 25518 (cc1) score 388 or sacrifice child
[1744367.676665] Killed process 25518 (cc1) total-vm:242352kB, anon-rss:200608kB, file-rss:0kB
```

It's seems like a memory issue. I am taking reference form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149613/installing-lxml-with-pip-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10-error-command-gcc-failed)

Comment: try: `sudo pip install lxml` ? Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6504860/2026508

Comment: tried that also. anyways, i am logged in as the root. its a problem of `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)` not user or group issue.

Comment: Are you running this inside a resource-limited virtual machine?

Comment: It's an old question. The Issue was solved by increasing ram size.

Comment: None of these answers worked for me, so I used `apt-get install python-lxml` (for Python 3, use `apt-get install python3-lxml`). This worked for me after already having installed other packages that have been mentioned, so they may be dependencies. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28270704/513397

Answer (score 132, accepted):

In this particular case, it has nothing to do with dependencies, it's a memory problem.

I had this problem within a virtualbox VM. My solution was to increase memory allocated to the VM from the default 512Mb to 1024Mb.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too...  On another note, this feels like a huge RED FLAG that this library requires so much memory just to compile! That's insane. Makes me glad I only use xml for this particular project.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, that's it!!! two days looking for a solution. Translation into Catalan: "Si pogués et donaria un petó!!! porto dos dies intentant sol·luconar-ho"

Comment: How on earth can it take more than 512 mb ram to compile a library! that is just sick

Answer (score 164):

Possible solution (if you have no ability to increase memory on that machine) is to add swap file.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

from https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1880#issuecomment-9920484

This worked for me on smallest digital ocean machine

Comment: You might want to turn off the swap after you're done: `sudo swapoff /swapfile`

Comment: @psychok7 as specified by Aaron Ash you can just turn swap off with `sudo swapoff /swapfile` and delete this swapfile like any other file.

Answer (score 19):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504860/261718

Go install some dev packages before *pip install lxml*

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
```

Comment: This is the right answer to a different issue, which is missing OS-level dependencies. That is not the problem salman has.

Answer (score 5):

Using digitalocean smallest machine you can just turn off mysql and apache while compiling using

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

and after installing lxml turn them on again using this commands with 'start' instead of 'stop'. Works pretty well for me without using swap file

Comment: Thanks to your comment "digitalocean" I found the solution

Answer (score 3):

If @Drake answer does not work for you try adding `lib1g-dev`.

`$ sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev`