# How to install lxml on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, lxml

First, I have found this question:

> [How to install lxml on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504810/how-to-install-lxml-on-ubuntu)

But after I tried all the answers on that page, it didn't resolve my problem. My problem is:

When I try to install lxml, the error is:

```
Installing egg-scripts.
uses namespace packages but the distribution does not require setuptools.
Getting distribution for 'lxml==3.0.1'.
Building lxml version 3.0.1.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__getFilenameForFile’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26310:7: warning: variable ‘__pyx_clineno’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int __pyx_clineno = 0;
       ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26309:15: warning: variable ‘__pyx_filename’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   const char *__pyx_filename = NULL;
               ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26308:7: warning: variable ‘__pyx_lineno’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int __pyx_lineno = 0;
       ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__tostring’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:98614:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlBufLength’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       __pyx_t_6 = ((PyObject *)__Pyx_decode_c_string(((char *)((unsigned char *)xmlBufContent(__pyx_v_c_result_buffer))), 0, xmlBufLength(__pyx_v_c_result_buffer), NULL, NULL, PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[6]; __pyx_lineno = 137; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L16;}
       ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:132608:81: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_self->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 543; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L9;}
                                                                                 ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:130569:52: note: expected ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *’ but argument is of type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *’
 static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {
                                                    ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133997:79: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   __pyx_t_1 = ((PyObject *)__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(((struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *)__pyx_v_stylesheet->_context))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[2]; __pyx_lineno = 680; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                               ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:130569:52: note: expected ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *’ but argument is of type ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *’
 static struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext *__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy(struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext *__pyx_v_self) {
                                                    ^
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12128:13: warning: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_displayNode(xmlNode *__pyx_v_c_node, PyObject *__pyx_v_indent) {
             ^
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
An error occurred when trying to install lxml 3.0.1. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing egg-scripts.
  Getting distribution for 'lxml==3.0.1'.
Error: Couldn't install: lxml 3.0.1
```

My Ubuntu is `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`.

Comment: [Other threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455238/lxml-installation-error-ubuntu-14-04-internal-compiler-error) have mentioned the exit status 4 being a memory problem. Do you have enough memory during compilation?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. After I increased my memory. It works!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libxslt1 python-libxslt1-dbg
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As @univerio said, the problem was memory:)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

http://lxml.de/installation.html