# Django Bad Handshake when run from Apache server but not from Django development server

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm getting the following error `('bad handshake: SysCallError(0, None)',)` when I run `response = requests.get(film_url)` from a website running a Django application in 'production' (ie an Apache2 webserver).

I do not get this error when I run the system from my laptop using the Django development server.  film_url is a link to a film (it could be any) on RottenTomatoes.com, for example  `https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/myfilm`

I'm running python 2.7 and I take it this is an SSL issue but I don't know how to sort.  I've tried to following this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578439/using-requests-with-tls-doesnt-give-sni-support/18579484#18579484) but I'm getting an error trying to install pyOpenSSL, namely:

```
Command "/var/www/mga/env/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-DuLMZe/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-giimpi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/mga/env/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DuLMZe/cryptography/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441668/error-while-installing-cryptography-using-pip), which basically says this error has occurred due because of the low resources on server.

Solution is:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```