# Error: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, lxml

I am installing odoo system in a virtual environment. I had problems installing lxml module.

I am using "pip --trusted-host pypi.python.org install lxml" command, but I receive an error. I have tried to download the sources, but the same error occurs. I am using Python 2.7.9 under Linux:

```
(odoo)odoo@des [~]# python -V
Python 2.7.9
(odoo)odoo@des [~]# uname -a
Linux des.desytec.com 2.6.32-042stab104.1 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 12:58:41 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have read a lot of pages telling about this problem. Some say that it is a memory problem and others say that libxml is missing. Both cases don't apply to me. What else could be?

```
Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-3.4.2.tar.gz (3.5MB)
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.17
    Minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.17, found 1.1.23
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.2.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.17
    Minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.17, found 1.1.23
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-idzRLz/lxml/src/lxml/inclu$
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:239:
    /tmp/pip-build-idzRLz/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:19:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxml2 is 2.7.0
    /tmp/pip-build-idzRLz/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:28:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_9XMLParser___init__’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103123: error: ‘XML_PARSE_HUGE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103123: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103123: error: for each function it appears in.)
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_10Schematron_6__call__’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:176893: error: ‘XML_SCHEMATRON_OUT_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/odoo/odoo/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-idzRLz/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(toke$
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    Building lxml version 3.4.2.

    Building without Cython.
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Everything was decided by setting several libraries

`sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev`

Solution has been found thanks [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149613/installing-lxml-with-pip-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10-error-command-gcc-failed?rq=1) and [second](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/11188375)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Installing lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) you can see that the latest lxml requires **libxml2 version 2.7.0 or later** and **libxslt version 1.1.23 or later**, which haven't been installed on your system.

you can:

- **Update** your libxslt, **e.x.** download rpm [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libxslt-devel)
- If there isn't a right version supporting for your system(like **CentOS 5**), you can choose an order version like **lxml 2.2.2** which is also suitable for lots of situations.