# pip install pymssql fails on Debian 8

Tags: python-2.7, debian, pip, freetds, pymssql

I am trying to install pymssql

```
pip install pymssql
```

for Python 2.7 on a Debian 8 machine, however it keeps failing on me.

I have already installed the following dependencies after running ***apt-get update*** and ***apt-get upgrade:***

- freetds-dev
- freetds-bin
- python-dev
- python-pip

I am getting the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.1.3.tar.gz (897kB): 897kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-e7ebv1/pymssql/setup.py) egg_info  for package pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '8.5', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.4')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

    Installed /tmp/pip-build-e7ebv1/pymssql/setuptools_git-1.1-py2.7.egg

Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '8.5', '')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.4')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    building '_mssql' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-e7ebv1/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-k9mYEi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'

setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')

setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('debian', '8.5', '')

setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.4')

setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS

setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']

setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']

running install

running build

running build_ext

building '_mssql' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-e7ebv1/pymssql/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-k9mYEi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e7ebv1/pymssql
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

The error seems to be originating from directories that are perhaps assumed to be following this order: (from the same error)

```
setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
```

In order to get rid of this error and successfuly install pymssql, do I have to install/update the program that terminated and showed this error? (which is, am assuming: ***x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc***) or are there other dependencies I am not aware of ?

Comment: Does your computer / virtual machine have enough memory? See for example [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25916353/5781248). Error message "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)" is the most relevant part of that error message.

Comment: It was a memory problem indeed. The machine was exhausted by too many zombie processes. I had to kill them using `pkill _processname_ ` . Thanks @martineau

Comment: The thanks for the suggestion about memory should go to @J.J. Hakala, not me — all I did was pretty-up your question...

Comment: Apologies. I meant to thank @J.J.Hakala

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have build-essential installed then install it if that doesn't work try this. [Installing lxml with pip in virtualenv Ubuntu 12.10 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149613/installing-lxml-with-pip-in-virtualenv-ubuntu-12-10-error-command-gcc-failed)

Comment: Solved. Problem in my case was related to memory being almost full. Not related to dependencies.