# Building android gives me error

Tags: android, build, android-source, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have been trying to build android gingerbread source. I am following the ubuntu 12.04.
I have installed all the packages as said but still I get this error while building android file system

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzo2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
```

I installed these libraries following suggestions from this link

https://community.freescale.com/thread/303536

But now a new problem came and its 
cannot find -lz

I checked it if it is installed through

ldconfig -p | grep lz

it says

```
liblzo2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2
liblzo2.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/liblzo2.so.2
liblzo2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so
liblzo2.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/liblzo2.so
liblzma.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
```

does it mean I have lz but not linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373995/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lz

Comment: sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev  worked from that thread. I didn't found that question in my previous searches.