# Failed to install Cabal-1.20.0.2

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I get this error when I'm trying to install Cabal-1.20.0.2:

```
$ cabal install Cabal-1.20.0.2.tar.gz 
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Cabal-1.20.0.2...
Failed to install Cabal-1.20.0.2
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/yonutix/.cabal/logs/Cabal-1.20.0.2.log ):
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.20.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (
/tmp/Cabal-1.20.0.2-11804/Cabal-1.20.0.2/Distribution/Simple/Utils.hs:386:31:
Warning:
In the use of ‘runGenProcess_’
(imported from System.Process.Internals):
Deprecated: "Please do not use this anymore, use the ordinary
'System.Process.createProcess'. If you need the SIGINT handling, use
delegate_ctlc = True (runGenProcess_ is now just an imperfectly emulated stub
that probably duplicates or overrides your own signal handling)."
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
)
```

I need to install this package because cabal-install depends on it.

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Here's a clue: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp` - ghc can't find libgmp. What OS are you using? How did you install ghc? Are you using the Haskell Platform?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 fresh installed, Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 for Linux, 64bit                $ /usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld: no input files

Comment: you could try this: `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev` - I wouldn't be surprised if a vanilla Ubuntu dist doesn't contain libgmp by default.

Comment: It worked, thanks, post it as answer, now I'm having a problem during the build step "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz"

Comment: I haven't used Ubuntu in a very long time, but if I were to hazard a guess, I think you need to install `zlib1g-dev` (bottom line being you need zlib development libraries).

Comment: ...and if that doesn't work see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3373995/349384.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is indicated by this part of the log file:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
```

ghc can't find libgmp. Most likely fix is to install the `libgmp-dev` package, e.g. under Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```