# Dockerfile fails with llvm-config error for numba install

Tags: docker, llvm, numba, pypy

My Dockerfile using a pypy base fails with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config' when installing llvmlite, a dependency of numba which is listed in my requirements.txt

I tried to follow and update the instructions here
[Python numba / llvmlite on Debian 8 - i can't build llvmlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495356/python-numba-llvmlite-on-debian-8-i-cant-build-llvmlite)

My error in more detail:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py): started
Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/local/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ux49fegr/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ux49fegr/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8s6wwump --python-tag pp371
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ux49fegr/llvmlite/
Complete output (26 lines):
running bdist_wheel
/usr/local/bin/pypy3 /tmp/pip-install-ux49fegr/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-install-ux49fegr/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 105, in main_posix
    out = subprocess.check_output([llvm_config, '--version'])
  File "/usr/local/lib-python/3/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib-python/3/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib-python/3/subprocess.py", line 722, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib-python/3/subprocess.py", line 1354, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'llvm-config'
```

I don't want the heavy weight of a conda installation. Is there a way to achieve a numba install for pypy without it?

```
FROM pypy:3.6-slim-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg wget software-properties-common
RUN wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | apt-key add - 15CF4D18AF4F7421
RUN apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/stretch/ llvm-toolchain-stretch-6.0 main"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cython python-llvm build-essential libedit-dev
RUN apt-get -y install libllvm6.0 llvm-6.0-dev llvm-dev

RUN pip install enum34
ENV LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/lib/llvm-6.0-dev/bin/llvm-config pip install llvmlite
ENV LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/lib/llvm-6.0-dev/bin/llvm-config pip install numba
# ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/llvm-6.0-dev/lib/

#... other stuff

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-dev \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential

# Add requirements
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/

# Install sphinx first as it does not work inside requirements
RUN pip install -U pip && pip install -U sphinx && pip install numpy && pip install cython &&  \
  pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

I expect a clean build of the docker image with numba on pypy

Comment: try with `FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9 RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk ` then install it through pip

Comment: I am trying to use pypy3.6 not python 3.7, already been successful with python3.7 docker image. Also prefer to use Debian stretch as Alpine does not come with many of the libraries I need.

Answer (score 9):

**WORKAROUND** If the error appeared after April the 17th (they released a new version, see [history](https://pypi.org/project/llvmlite/0.32.0/#history)).
As a workaround try installing a previous version

```py
pip3 install llvmlite==0.31.0
```

Comment: its no longer available says my pip :(

Comment: Before installing llvmlite I had to update pip and setuptools. Otherwise llvmlite installation failed.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment numba [won't install on python 3.9](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/621#issuecomment-727142311).

I changed my base docker image from `python:3.9-slim` to `python:3.8-slim` and then `pip install numba` succeeded

Comment: As of now, the source repositories of `llvmlite` and `numba` have been updated to work with Python 3.9, so installation from clones of the repositories works, following the documentation at: http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#compiling-llvmlite and https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installing.html#installing-from-source.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me -

```
RUN echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libedit-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  llvm-8 llvm-8-dev

RUN LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-8 pip3 install enum34 llvmlite numba
```

Used version 8, because got an error with the latest llvm version -

```
RuntimeError: Building llvmlite requires LLVM 7.0.x, 7.1.x or 8.0.x, got '3.7.1'
```

Reference - https://apt.llvm.org/

Comment: how to run these commands on win os? i mean apt-get ?

Comment: This will require some research, you might want to try your luck with the windows builds - https://llvm.org/builds/

Comment: do i just install it and run? but docker will need to pull it too right? when building the image?

Comment: Are you building a windows docker image? or are you building a linux docker image on windows?

Comment: at first i was building win docker image, but llvm lite bug popped up - i googled the solution, but the only solution was the code above using apt-get so now i think i m using ubuntu image - i m using that link you gave

Comment: here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559344/how-to-make-apt-get-run-in-windows-in-docker-file

Answer (score 0):

The "real" solution would be to encourage [llvmlite](http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/contributing.html) and/or [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/contributing.html) to release a wheel for pypy. But for the immediate problem...

Somehow you are missing an llvm installation, at least according to [apt-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file):

```
$ apt-file find llvm-config |grep llvm-6
llvm-6.0: /usr/bin/llvm-config-6.0
llvm-6.0: /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/bin/llvm-config
llvm-6.0: /usr/share/man/man1/llvm-config-6.0.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing `numba` on Python 3.9 on macOS, the following works:

```sh
# install llvm using MacPorts
sudo port install llvm-10
sudo port install llvm_select
sudo port select --set llvm mp-llvm-10
# set environment variable used when building `llvmlite`
export LLVM_CONFIG=/opt/local/bin/llvm-config

# clone, build, and install `llvmlite`
# http://llvmlite.pydata.org/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#compiling-llvmlite
git clone git@github.com:numba/llvmlite.git
cd llvmlite
python setup.py build
python runtests.py
python setup.py install
cd ..

# clone, build, and install `numba`
# https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installing.html#installing-from-source
git clone git@github.com:numba/numba.git
cd numba
export PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH  # use clang, same as used for building Python 3.9
pip install -v .
cd ..
```

The above are with:

- `llvmlite` at commit 334411cf638c8e06ba19bfda16b07dd64e9dac3c, and
- `numba` at commit ca8132ba5e43fc3f79767046ed55217aeeabb35e.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286131/how-do-i-install-llvm-10-on-ubuntu-18-04
I added to Dockerfile the lines

```
RUN apt-get -y install llvm-10*

RUN rm -f  /usr/bin/llvm-config

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-config-10 /usr/bin/llvm-config
```

and It worked (`llvmlite` installed)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, obtained from this [github issues thread](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/issues/625), that worked for me! Essentially, `pip` just needed an upgrade in the Dockerfile before installing libraries. All I needed to do was add this line in my Dockerfile:

```
--upgrade pip \
```

Here is the sample of my Dockerfile:

```
# Docker commands here ...
RUN APT_INSTALL="apt-get install -y " && \
PIP_INSTALL="python3 -m pip install " && \
apt-get update && \
# more docker commands here ...
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive $APT_INSTALL \
python3.6 \
python3.6-dev \
python3-distutils-extra \
python3-pip && \
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3 && \
$PIP_INSTALL \
    --upgrade pip \ # adding this line was my solution
    setuptools \
    && \
$PIP_INSTALL \
    numpy==1.18.5 \
# more docker commands here...
```

This is for python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with python3.8 but the final resolution was just to update my PIP to version 23.0.1 and it solved the problem.

Comment: It was directly related to the llvmlite but installing pip 23 resolved it and I updated it a bit differently to as the standard upgrade command did not bring pip up.  python -m pip install --upgrade pip   the standard upgrade command did not bring pip up to version23.   Hope that helps!