# how to make apt-get run in windows in docker file?

Tags: docker, package-managers

How to make these dockerfile commands run on windows10? I m building my docker image - do i need to replace 'apt-get' by windows-compatible package manager?

```
FROM python:3.6.5
RUN mkdir -p ./voice_flask/d
WORKDIR /voice_flask/d

COPY . /voice_flask/d
# RUN pip3 install llvmlite==0.31.0


RUN echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /voice_flask/d/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /voice_flask/d/sources.list

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libedit-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  llvm-8 llvm-8-dev

RUN LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-8 pip3 install enum34 llvmlite numba

#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: @MarkoE, thx u sir for helping me...

Comment: @MarkoE, i updated the question with the full dockerfile code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the latest Ubuntu, llvmlite and numba installs directly with pip3.

Here's a sample Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install enum34 llvmlite numba
CMD ["/bin/echo", "hello world"]
```

Build: `docker build . -t llvm_docker`

Run: `docker run -t llvm_docker`

Output: `hello world`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an official image as a parent image. For example, you can use the ubuntu image `ubuntu:latest` to execute the commands above. Then I guess it look like the following code:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-8 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libedit-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  llvm-8 llvm-8-dev

RUN LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/bin/llvm-config-8 pip3 install enum34 llvmlite numba
```

Maybe it is useful for you to do a [first simple example dockerfile](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/java/chapters/ch03-build-image.adoc#create-your-first-image):

```sh
FROM ubuntu:latest

CMD ["/bin/echo", "hello world"]
```

Comment: can i include 2 base images? like
from python3.6.5.
from ubuntu?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can use a [Dockerfile.build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds) or you can use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). Otherwise there is also a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nitincypher/docker-ubuntu-python-pip/) with ubuntu and python preinstalled. Or you run the install commands in your image.

Comment: i just pulled docker image in the last link, but it still can't create a container.

Comment: yes, it says it can't find llvm version 8, probably cuz it's outdated, now the latest is 12. i will update u flaxel - big thx for your support..