# Linux Ubuntu- /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2

Tags: c++, linux, linker, linker-errors, ubuntu-20.04

I'm building a project from github but after running `make build` I got an error message below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ld 

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried installing lib stated from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373995/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lz) and the error changed to:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`