# Linking against .a, but still need .so? (C++, linux)

Tags: c++, linux, linker, runtime, libraries

Under what circumstances would I link an application against a bunch of .a files, but still require .so files at runtime?

Comment: did you used linker flag `-static`?

Answer (score 1):

> Under what circumstances would I link an application against a bunch
>   of .a files, but still require .so files at runtime?

**A situation in which a specific .so needs to be loaded during runtime**

For example, you may have two shared object libraries(.so's):

```
RealCarLibrary
TestCarLibrary
```

But you need to load either the Test library or the Real library, during runtime, depending on what the user's environment variable $CAR_LIB is set to.

```
typedef int (*runCar_ptr)();
const char* env_variable = std::getenv("CAR_LIB");
void *sharedObject_ptr = nullptr;
if(env_variable == "test" )
{
   sharedObject_ptr =dlopen("/path/to/TestCarLibrary.so", RTLD_NOW);
}
else
{
  sharedObject_ptr = dlopen("/path/to/RealCarLibrary.so", RTLD_NOW);
}
runCar_ptr *runCarFunctionPtr = dlsym(sharedObject_ptr, "RunTheCar");
runCarFunctionPtr();
```

**A synopsis of .a vs .so:**

Archive libraries(.a) are statically linked(at compile time). The resulting binary contains both the program you created and the library.

Shared Object libraries(.so) are loaded in at runtime. They incur a lower overall memory footprint, since they aren't actually added to the binary you are creating.

**As for why one might choose to use static libraries, you have to look at the pro's of static libraries**

`To guarantee(at build time) that an application's libraries are present and that they are the correct version.`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237282/whats-the-difference-between-so-la-and-a-library-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files) for more info on Shared Object Library vs Static.