# How can I solve this ? error: unable to find library -lmysqlclient

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, shared-libraries, freebsd

I want to compile for my program and I am stuck here , I am usig freebsd 12.1 and gcc++6.4 + gnu gmake -j20 comand

Curent path

```
# mysql
INCDIR += -I../../../extern/mysql
LIBDIR += -L/usr/local/lib/mysq
LIBS   += -lmysqlclient -lz -pthread -lm -lssl -lcrypto
### END
```

Error in putty

```
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src # gmake -j20
linking ../game
ld: error: unable to find library -lmysqlclient
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [Makefile:228: ../game] Error 1
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src #
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src #
```

I edited the typo and now i am geeting this

```
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src # gmake -j20
linking ../game
ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(client.c.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(libmysql.c.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
ld: error: /usr/local/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(crypt_genhash_impl.cc.o) is incompatible with elf_i386_fbsd
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [Makefile:228: ../game] Error 1
root@vps:/usr/src/Sursa/Server/source/game/src #
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mysqlclient` can be found at `/usr/local/lib/mysq` ?

Comment: Yes , and olso I have it on /usr/src/Sursa/Server/extern/mysql/lib

Comment: https://gyazo.com/124095963e45ebc91e58490ad637fafa

Comment: A `.a` lib is for Windows (Mingw uses it). Libs in Linux are `.so`

Comment: how can i make it .so for Freebsd 12.1?

Comment: You must download and install the proper version for your Freebsd,  not for Windows

Comment: from where ? wich pkg it s ?

Comment: @Ripi2 Your comment is wrong. `.a` files are object archives, used on many Unix-like systems.

Comment: @arrowd You' re totally right. For starters [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237282/whats-the-difference-between-so-la-and-a-library-files). When I saw the picture in the OP's comment I inmediately thought of Window's MinGW library naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `LIBDIR += -L/usr/local/lib/mysq` - missing `l`.

Make sure you have `mysql57-client` package installed. If not, run `pkg install mysql57-client`.

Also, `/usr/src` dir is usually used to store FreeBSD source code. It is not a best idea to use it to store your own code.

Comment: what is a  typo  ? .. and how can I fix it ?

Comment: @Metin2Problem "typo" = "typographic error". You missed `l` at the end of `mysq`

Comment: @Ripi2 I installed mysq 5.7 and i am getting ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: @Metin2Problem A different error requires a different question in this site.

Comment: @Ripi2 see the update . new error after solving the typo

Comment: @Metin2Problem No, don't do that. Edit again and reverese to previous version. The point of this site is not a chat, but a place for future readers may found a solution for their issues. If you change things like you did then the goal is lost by ofuscation.

Comment: @Metin2Problem And if the solution for your original issue was solved by this answer then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)