# How to fix "cannot find -lz"

Tags: c, linux, zlib

I am working on code have Zlib.h header, This header is found in my code folder, I compile this code by using

```
gcc -o x xx.c -lz
```

but I get on this

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This happen just with Linux that I installed in a VBox.
How to fix that.

Comment: Try `gcc -lz -o x xx.c`

Comment: The same problem!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcc-command-in-linux-with-examples/

Comment: you need to install zlib

Comment: Why I need for that if I have zlib.h header ?!

Comment: @oleva the header may not contain any code at all, just the predefined macros and function prototypes

Comment: Can I get on zlib? and use it in my code? I do not want to use it from the installation

Comment: In most cases a header is only a description for the compiler what you may find in the related library. Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use installed zlib? The alternative is to download an compile on your own.

Comment: zlib is such a simple library (and buildable with cmake, woot), there shouldn't be a problem with getting  the source ,building it locally, and linking with either the static or shared libraries.

Comment: @Gerhardh, because the installation use just with Linux, I want to use my code on Linux and win .

Comment: How can I get on the source of zlib? and how to link it with my code?

Comment: Have you checked  [zlib site](https://zlib.net/)? There are links to download the sources.

Comment: What is the correct way that I should use if I use zlib.h as a header not by installation, please?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `gcc foo.c`, you ask `gcc` to compile and link the given file.

#### 1. Compilation

Compilation consist of transforming the source file into an object file.
This step need the included files, like `zlib.h` to be found by gcc.

This step seems to be correct on system.

NB: You can ask `gcc` to only do this step typing `gcc -c foo.c`, or better `gcc -Wall -c foo.c`

#### 2. Link

Once the object files have be created, then need to be linked to create an executable file.

It's that step that failed for you: your linked can't find the already compiled functions needed by your code.

When linking with option `-lz`, you tell your linker "search for `libz.so` file to find the missing functions"

On current linux distribution, you can install package like `libz-dev` to install the `.so` file in well known places. (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`...)

If you don't have the libz.so file installed on the library search path, you can specify where is the library to your linker.

For instance, if `libz.so` is if `/bar/baz` directory, you can type `gcc foo.c /bar/baz/libz.so`. The same for `libz.a`.

---

In any case, you'll need the `libz.so` file or at least the `libz.a` file

See also [What's the difference between .so, .la and .a library files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12237282/1212012)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing 'zlib1g-dev'. On Ubuntu this following command will install the library.

> sudo apt install zlib1g-dev