# static library what is the difference between "la" library and "a" library

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries

I build an open source application and I found that the compilator generate `.la` libray file and `.a` library file

What is the difference between both files?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238035/what-is-libtools-la-file-for