# What is libtool's .lai file for?

Tags: libtool

Can somebody tell me what libtool's .lai file is for?

See also [What are libtool's .la file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238035/what-is-libtools-la-file-for)

Comment: I'm asking because a .lai file is not a .la file, just as a .la file is not an .a file.

Comment: Ok, I removed the flag. Sorry for missing that extra `i`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.lai` is the extension of a file that will be installed as an `.la` file. In other words, `i` is appended in order to show that it is in a temporary "staging" state.

What the `i` stands for is anyone's guess. My guess is that it has something to do with "install".

Comment: "intermediate" perhaps?